# Tokbox session is not connecting in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, tokbox

When user login in the application I am connecting the **Tokbox** session which is successfully working. But if logout now and disconnect the session and login again then tokbox session is not getting connected.
Following error is coming

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OTSessionErrorDomain error 1006.)

I have checked the session and token and they are valid.

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

Based on the error code, it looks like you're having a connection issue. Could you please confirm that you've successfully disconnected (and receive the callback) before you attempt to reconnect?

Comment: @Manik, I figured it out and the issue was resolved now. Thanks!!

Comment: got the same issue, can you explain how you resolved that. And you can post your answere and accept it as right one for your question\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the disconnect of TokBox session.
use this to disconnect from the TokBox:-

```
session!.disconnect(&error)
if error != nil {
        print("Session Error while Disconnecting session: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
} else{
        print("disconnectFromSession: Session disconnection request sent")

}
```